# How does Status increase or decrease in Rippers Resurrected?

Tags: savage-worlds

I'm reading through the rules for status, Favors, and Scandals in *Savage World — Rippers Resurrected*. The monthly salary, Favor cost table, and gaining favors all makes sense, but I don't see any mention of how a player can change change their Status other than taking Rich Edge, Filthy Rich Edge, or Poverty Hindrance. Are these the only ways or am i simply missing something here?

Comment: Do not answer in comments.

Comment: @mxyzplk My hope was to give something that would help people find a full answer, but if we are going to delete that, okay.

Comment: [Should users refrain from answers (or partial answers) in comments?](//meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/6533)

Comment: @Thunderforge Partial answers are still answers. If you provide your information there, others can improve on it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the Resurrected edition changes - so sorry if this answer is useless -  but in the old one (2005), you can influence the status with:

- Edges & Hindrances - the ones you mention, plus Noble(+5) and Disowned (-3)
- Behaviour & Actions - buying cheap things when having status over 10 (-1); being seen travelling in undignified conditions (-1); lodging in a Lodge with a Resource level below their status (-1);
  On a monthly basis you can also +/- your status:

  - behaviour unfitting of your status (borrowing money, scandal, shabby appearance, gracelessness, travelling armed, divorce false accusations, arrest) gives a -1
  - buying property in excess of 500£, marrying up or consistent polite behaviour (to those who count) gives you a +1
- Risking status to try and influence others with Intimidation, Persuasion,
  Streetwise or Taunt rolls (or opposing them) - you can risk up to half your status, getting a +1 for every point you risk. If you fail you loose the status (loose double on a critical fail)
- giving up status for monetary gain - selling your valuables (1S for 10£; 2S for 100£ - family heirloom or such; 4S for 1000£ - land, property)
- socializing events (+ or -, depending on actions)